# How to activate wordpress plugins through FTP/cpanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

Due to some problem I made deactivate all the plugins in my wordpress plugin menu.
Then again I tried to enter into the *wp-admin* menu it shows 
Call to undefined function *wp_cache_get()* /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1113
I want to make active all the plugins again.

Comment: You cant active through FTP but using database is possible

Comment: How,can you plz explain it

Comment: Possible answers in this url http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199798/activate-a-plugin-through-phpmyadmin-or-ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// You can active any plugin vai the Functions.php file.Here the functions.php code.

```
function activate_plugin_wc() {
    $active_plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    array_push($active_plugins, 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php'); /* Here just replace  plugin directory and plugin file*/
    update_option( 'active_plugins', $active_plugins );    
}
add_action( 'init', 'activate_plugin_wc' );
```

Comment: How would you go about activating 10 plugins? Assuming this one activates 1 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress save all the active plugin list in `wp_options` table `option_name` => **active_plugins** and `option_value` => serialize value of all the active plugin with if first load file name and `autoload` => `yes`.

> Sample value of `option_value`

`a:2:{i:0;s:27:"woocommerce/woocommerce.php";i:1;s:41:"wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php";}`

after unserialize it, it will look some thing like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => woocommerce/woocommerce.php
    [1] => wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php
)
```